# How do I determine which chipset (say X58, X79) my motherboard uses from ami bios?

Tags: bios

The BIOS (v02.69) of my old PC looks like this

[image]

How do I determine which chipset (say X58, X79) the motherboard uses?

each time I try to login my windows 10, it restarts immediately, so I cannot find the info from windows.

Comment: Is this the actual photo?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look up Xeon E5645 on [Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/48768/intel-xeon-processor-e5645-12m-cache-2-40-ghz-5-86-gt-s-intel-qpi.html). It uses the LGA 1366 socket.

Then check Wikipedia for [LGA 1366](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1366#Supported_chipsets). The *Supported chipsets* section tells us that:

> The chipsets that support LGA 1366 are Intel's X58 (desktop) and 3400, 3420, 3450, 5500, 5520 and 7500 (server).

If that's a desktop motherboard, then it's most likely using the X58 chipset.

An interesting exception are motherboards by some Chinese brands such as Jingsha or Machinist. These actually use refurbished server-grade chipsets C602 and C612, despite being marketed as X79 and X99 respectively. As far as I know you can't tell the difference just by looking at the BIOS setup.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I tell the difference to check if I'm using that kind of motherboards?

Comment: You'd have to either boot an OS and run some hardware info tool (Speccy, HWiNFO etc.) or remove the cooler (if present) from the chipset and inspect markings on it.